# Sphinx latex: cross referencing does not work inside a heading :ref:

Tags: python, latex, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I want to cross-reference chapters to one another using the sphinx package and generating the documentation in LaTeX format with `make latexpdf`.

The link from the script.rst to the conf.rst works, but the other way around it does not work. The only difference is that in latex the reference should be inside `\section{}` command because of the underlying ^^^^.

When generating the documentation in confluence everything works fine.

Do you know what might be the cause of this issue? Thank you!

**conf.rst**

```
.. _conf_file.yaml:

conf.yaml
=========

Configuration parameters for :ref:`script.py`
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

**script.rst**

```
.. _script.py:

script.py
=========

This is the documentation on script ``script``. Please see the config file: :ref:`conf_file.yaml`
```

**conf.py**

```
# -- General configuration ---------------------------------------------------

# Add any Sphinx extension module names here, as strings. They can be
# extensions coming with Sphinx (named 'sphinx.ext.*') or your custom
# ones.
extensions = [
    'sphinx.ext.autodoc',
    'sphinx.ext.napoleon',
    'sphinx.ext.todo',
    'sphinxarg.ext',
    'sphinxcontrib.confluencebuilder',
    'rinoh.frontend.sphinx',
]

# -- Options for LaTeX output ------------------------------------------------

latex_elements = {
    # The paper size ('letterpaper' or 'a4paper').
    #
    # 'papersize': 'letterpaper',

    # The font size ('10pt', '11pt' or '12pt').
    #
    # 'pointsize': '10pt',

    # Additional stuff for the LaTeX preamble.
    #
    # 'preamble': '',

    # Latex figure (float) alignment
    #
    # 'figure_align': 'htbp',

    'fncychap': r'\usepackage[Bjornstrup]{fncychap}'
}

# Grouping the document tree into LaTeX files. List of tuples
# (source start docname, target name, title,
#  author, theme [manual, howto or own class]).
master_doc = 'index'
latex_documents = [
    (master_doc, 'documentation.tex', 'Project',
     'Andreea', 'manual'),
]
numfig = True
```

Comment: You tagged this with _rinohtype_, but that doesn't seem to be relevant since you're using the LaTeX builder? Sidenote: you do not need to add `'rinoh.frontend.sphinx'` to the extensions list for recent rinohtype versions. Especially not if you're not using the rinoh builder :-)

Comment: You're right! I have tried generating the pdf with rinoh and didn't work, but the extension remained and somehow I though that I need it for `make latexpdf` as well. Thanks! But this does not solve the problem...

Comment: If you think you encountered a bug in rinoh, I kindly invite you to create a [bug report ticket](https://github.com/brechtm/rinohtype/issues/new/choose).